# How to split a string in js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, split

I have a string like below and I want to split it and get the value before pipe `(|)`.

```
var str = "110|paris";
```

I just want to store like below,after split

```
var value = 100;
```

Comment: Please search over search engine once.

Comment: Typing the title of your question into Google literally gives you the answer as the first result. Please try to do at least some research before asking!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var value = str.split('|')[0];
```

will give you what's before the pipe. More generally:

```
var array = str.split('|');
```

this will give you an array with elements `['110', 'paris']` so:

```
array[0] // this is '110'
array[1] // this is 'paris'
```

Note that if you actually want a number `110` and not a string `'110'` then you should use `parseInt`:

```
parseInt(array[0], 10) // this is 110
```

Full example:

```
var str = '110|paris';
var array = str.split('|');
var value = parseInt(array[0], 10);
var city = array[1];
```

Now `value` is `100` (number) and `city` is `'paris'` (string).

Comment: Please you should not answer dupes

Comment: But you can't down vote. His answer is correct.

Comment: I agree, as the rules currently goes, there is nothing wrong with answering. So downvoting a correct answer seems way to harsh.

Comment: @Shubham Please refer following post: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate